# How to set threshold value

Tags: statistical-significance, percentage, threshold

Let me be very specific.This is how the dataset looks like-

For example, for a 6 years period,

**Number of students staying in a college**: 45,85,44,952,7955,1522.

**Number of students leaving the college**: 1000,86,49,30000,745,5699

**Method I am using**: for any pair,if (leaving/staying)*100 is above X%, then I will consider that the two number is significantly different and there is a notable difference between 2 values. The threshold percentage X determines if a pair is different.

**Example**: You can tell by seeing the data that (85-86), (44-49) are not so different if you look at the other pairs in the data.

I need to know how can I determine the threshold X that would generalize the sense that (952-30000) has a huge difference while (85-86) is not different if we compare it with the other pairs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel like you probably need to say something about what you're interested in investigating with this data, but at first glance it seems like it may come down to defining a value of X that would be of some practical importance (unless you're only interested in saying that $N_{leavers} \neq N_{stayers}$). Only you know what would be important for your purposes.

Comment: If this is data for a six year period your analysis should presumably take into account that fact. Do you have multiple time series?

Comment: Examine the difference in logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ian points out, I should mention why this approach might be better.

You want to test whether two values are equal, or close to equal. As you can see, the size of the difference between the two values is relative. So you resort to taking the % of the total that is in either of the two groups. Taking the ratio like that makes sense, as you get rid of the relativity of the absolute differences between the two groups. However, you also toss out the information about the **amount** of people in those groups.

This is vital information, as (1-1) has a lot less certainty about the true ratio between the two groups than (1000-1000). This is why you will almost never see percentages used like this in statistics. So let me propose another method to test if two groups are equally sized, while preserving the information about the total of the two groups.

---

What you are testing is as follows:

$H_0: x_{staying} = x_{leaving} \implies \frac{x_{staying}}{x_{staying}+x_{leaving}} = 0.5$
$H_1: x_{staying} \neq x_{leaving} \implies \frac{x_{staying}}{x_{staying}+x_{leaving}} \neq 0.5$

You can test whether this is true, or almost true, by doing a $\chi^2$-test ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test)).

---

For example (85-86):
You have a total of 171 persons, so given the $H_0$ you expect the amount of people staying to be the half of 171: $x_{staying,expected} = 0.5*x_{total} = 85.5$. Similarly you expect the amount of people leaving to be the half of 171: $x_{leaving,expected} = 0.5*x_{total} = 85.5$.

You can then calculate the $\chi^2$-value as follows:

$\chi^2 = \frac{(85-85.5)^2}{85.5} + \frac{(86-85.5)^2}{85.5} \approx 0.00584$

---

Example 2 (952-30000):

You have a total of 30952 persons, so given the $H_0$ you expect the amount of people staying to be the half of 30952: $x_{staying,expected} = 0.5*x_{total} = 15476$. Similarly you expect the amount of people leaving to be the half of 30952: $x_{leaving,expected} = 0.5*x_{total} = 15476$.

You can then calculate the $\chi^2$-value as follows:

$\chi^2 = \frac{(30000-15476)^2}{15476} + \frac{(952-15476)^2}{15476} \approx 27261.1238$

---

Because you have 1 degree of freedom (given the total number, if you pick one of the two values (leaving/staying) you automatically fix the other), the value calculated follows a $\chi^2_1$-distribution with 1 degree of freedom. This distribution denotes the probability of the data you find happening randomly if $H_0$ is true. Generally in statistics, if the probability of the result occurring randomly is lower than 0.05, the $H_0$ is rejected. This probability corresponds with the $\chi^2$-value of $3.841$. So the higher the value is, the 'more significant' the deviation from $H_0$ is.

Comment: While what you're saying might be an appropriate alternative approach for the OP to take, their question is about how to determine what value of $\frac{leaving}{staying} \times 100$ would be suitable to say that the difference is large. Your answer doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: Hmm, there is a reason for that. Let me add it into my answer.

Comment: The answer is still focused on testing whether the ratio is not 1:1. The OPs talk of the size of the differences still leaves me wondering whether what they're really wanting know is 1) how to test whether the difference is at least as large as some other ratio (say 2:1) and 2) how they might go about determining what that ratio ought to be. By way of a parallel, you provide a suggestion of how to test for statistical significance, but it's not clear that the OP isn't concerned with clinical significance. You may be right, but the question isn't currently clear enough to determine that.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I agree that the question is a bit vague. For now, I'll leave the answer in place, until the OP clarifies.

Comment: If you do update note that this is for six, presumably consecutive, years as I note in a comment on the question

Comment: _for any pair_: from this phrase in the OP I figured that he wants to draw a conclusion for each year independently.

Comment: thanks a lot @Jarko... i have been learning about the chi-squared test and found out that this is a possible approach. Your answer was of great help.

I cannot just use percentage because it rules out the fact that the number of people can be very small and yet the percentage be so large that I would consider it significant by mistake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i had a little bit of confusion in this statement- "Ho  is rejected if χ2 ≥3.841"..why is it 3.841?

Comment: @user3798510 I added some clarifications in my answer. I hope that helps. If not, feel free to ask :)

Comment: The chi-squared test is not a bad idea, but it lacks justification. It might be worth observing that your proposal is tantamount to a null hypothesis in which each year's pair of numbers are independent realizations from a common Poisson distribution (whose parameter evidently changes dramatically from one year to the next). This suggests two improvements: first, one could use the Poisson distribution to assess significance; second, one might look for related evidence that could bear on the plausibility of this somewhat strong assumption.